# Android webview app crash when trying to open tell link

Tags: java, android, android-webview, tel

Am trying to open a tel: link on android webview but it do crash my app, please how can someone help fix this or tell me what am doing wrong.

**MyAppWebViewClient.java**

```
package org.event2u.event2u;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("event2u.org")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            //view.reload();
            return true;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: show logcat  pleae

Comment: Add the crash log.

Comment: @TDG my code complied without error, but when i run the apk on my phone it will load very well except when i click on tel: link it will show `UNFORTUNATELY APP HAS STOPPED`

Comment: @PhilipJems Add crash logs from console in your Android studio

Comment: @Rahul please let me install emulator, i have been texting my apk direct on my phone

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with this code and the app doesn't crash.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

         }
    }
```

I think the problem it crash is because you say this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```